# displaying icons instead of thumbnails

Tags: windows-10, icons, thumbnails, windows-photo-gallery

In windows 10, Windows Live Photo Gallery displays icons and not thumbnails. I have tried EVERYTHING with no results. (Well, not quite everything. dod not do the command prompt thing.) I finally resorted to uninstalling it, but now I cannot find any download to reinstall it.

Comment: so what are you asking for a link to download it ?

Answer (score 0):

Start button > Control Panel > classic view > Folder Options > View tab >UN-check the first box " Always show icons never thumbnails " > OK

Microsoft website prompts Windows Photo Gallery was a part of Windows Essentials 2012 suite reached end of support on January 10, 2017. It is no longer available for download.
But I find that you could try to download it from the link below.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/forum/gallery-program/where-to-download-windows-essentials-2012/7665b354-4f2b-445d-811e-9d8c98e8f872

Comment: I tried this; didn't work. As I said, I tried everything.